# Is it possible to FTP a file to an external location that currently exists in the Marketing Cloud ftp location?

Tags: marketing-cloud

A file has been put in a folder on the Marketing Cloud ftp site. 
How do we move this file to an external FTP? Will 2 transfer activities in an automation accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

SFMC Support may have a custom extract type for handing this.  But, I've ran into this in the past and don't believe they do.

The file transfer activity can move data from the safehouse to an FileLocation you define (SFMC or external).  But, it cannot move files from FTP to FTP.

If your source data resides in marketing cloud (as a data extension or tracking extract), then i would recommend having two transfer step.  One that transfers the extract to SFMC FTP and one that transfers the extract to the external FTP.